# Perl uri_escape_utf8 inconsistent behaviour (or programmer error!)

Tags: perl, url, escaping

I'm trying to implement some URI encoding of filenames in my urls, but am experiencing some strange problems with uri_escape and uri_escape_utf8, where it appears to be behaving inconsistently.

Using the perl command line:

```
richard@magic-box:$ perl
use URI::Escape;
print uri_escape_utf8("\"quotes\"_in_a_filename.pdf");
%22quotes%22_in_a_filename.pdf
```

Perfect, just what I want.  Then in my code:

```
print STDERR uri_escape_utf8("\"quotes\"_in_a_filename.pdf");
print STDERR uri_escape("\"quotes\"_in_a_filename.pdf");
```

This results in my application log file getting the following lines:

```
"quotes"_in_a_filename.pdf
"quotes"_in_a_filename.pdf
```

Oddly, the same bit of code in the application works perfectly well with filenames with spaces, and (for example) correctly outputs:

```
my%20pdf%20with%20spaces.pdf
```

I am somewhat baffled, and don't know where to look next for solutions.  Any help gratefully appreciated.

Cheers,

R

Comment: When I run your first example program, I get `"quotes"_in_a_filename.pdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default set of unsafe characters has changed to those in RFC 3986 in version 1.53 of the URI distribution (see the [Changes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/Changes) file. Unfortunately, it seems the list of default chars hasn't been updated in the documentation yet. The old set was:

```
^A-Za-z0-9\-_.!~*'()
```

and it now is

```
^A-Za-z0-9\-\._~"
```

which excludes the `"` from the unsafe characters. I assume your application is using a different perl interpreter, or at least a different library location for the `URI::Escape` module. There is a discussion about your exact issue in [URI's bugtracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=56421).

Edit: If you want full consistency, I'd advise you to declare your own escape function that passes the unsafe character pattern in explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated!  I had toyed with the idea that URI::Escape would be different in the two different environments I was testing in, but wasn't sure how that would be possible, or why it would differ in this way.  I'll create my own escape sequence.

Thanks again, R